# Connecting openVPN windows 7 clients to the server

Tags: linux, windows-7, openvpn, samba

Apologies for the wording of the question - it was done in a rush, here with the altered wording:

I have an openVPN server running on Ubuntu 18.04 which has samba running.

I have no problems connecting openVPN clients running on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 and MacOs 10.13.6 to the samba shares but I just can't get windows 7 clients to connect to samba even though the server shows that they are connected and they ping the server without a problem.

But I get error - *0x8007274D - No connection made because the target machine actively refused it when using WAN miniport (SSTP)* - when trying to get Windows 7 clients to connect to the samba workgroup.

I have tried many host name combination such as smb://10.8.0.1 and many others. I get messages like:

error 0x80072AFC: The requested name is valid but no data of the requested type was found.

I have tried various UFW settings without luck. I seem to have exhausted my limited knowledge of networking.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: 1. Compare and contrast a working client configuration with a non-working client configuration. What's different? 2. Post the non-working client configuration here, remembering to obfuscate destination host, username/password, and certificate details. 3. Post the relevant lines from the server log showing what happens when (a) a successful connection is made, (b) when an unsuccessful connection is attempted

Comment: Ok please rewrite your question to make that clearer for everyone else

Answer (score 0):

in the end the answer was simple: window run utility - \[IP-address]\samba share (see your /etc/samba config file) so for eg: \10.8.0.1\samba-share and it connects perfectly.

Thanks to Karim Buzdar found at vitux.com